# Get the URL of an image using jumblr

Tags: url, casting, jumblr

I´m struggeling a bit trying to get the URL of a PhotoPost using jumblr.
I tried casting a post to a PhotoPost, but the detail says that there is no link ( i guess that is what i´m looking for)
All i want is the link to the jpg.

```
    List<Post> posts = client.userDashboard();
    PhotoPost photoPost = (PhotoPost) posts.get(0);
    System.out.println(photoPost.detail());

    {date=2015-06-15 23:14:28 GMT, format=html, link=null, caption=<blockquote><p>“…You win.”
    <br/></p><p>“I know.”</p></blockquote>, state=published, type=photo, slug=you-win-i-know,
```

I hope someone might have an idea.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

The Jumblr API can be very confusing and the examples aren't showing everything. 
I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("type", "photo");
List<Post> posts = client.blogPosts("YOURBLOGNAME.tumblr.com", params);
PhotoPost photoPost = (PhotoPost) posts.get(0);
System.out.println(photoPost.getPhotos().get(0).getOriginalSize().getUrl());
```

Change `YOURBLOGNAME` with your blogname. If `"YOURBLOGNAME.tumblr.com"` isn't working, use `"YOURBLOGNAME.com"` instead. This code gets the first image (`pho.getPhotos().get(0)`) of the first post (`(PhotoPost) posts.get(0)`).

Comment: Why was my answer edited to that nonsense with my account? Hmm... Well, whatever. Thank you Infinite Recursion to change it back